# is there any way to generate ParameterizedTypeReference Instance of generic type?

Tags: java

I have classes like this

```
class SomeWrapper<T> {
 private int code;
 private T value;
}
```

```
class SomeValue<T> {
 private String name;
 private T target;
}
```

So, I want to send some http request using RestTemplate in Spring.
I need ParameterizedTypeReference Object like this

```
new ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeWrapper<SomeValue>>();
```

but In my case, type of SomeValue class is changable
so I want to make some class like Facotry
for example like this way)

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeWrapper<SomeValue>> ptr = SomeFacotory.getParameterizedType(SomaValue.class);
```

is there any way to do like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can instantiate a `ParameterizedTypeReference` like this:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeWrapper<SomeValue>> ptr = new ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeWrapper<SomeValue>>() {};
```

You could also create a static method that will create it generically for you as well such as:

```
public static <T> ParameterizedTypeReference<T> getTypeReference() {
    return new ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {};
}
```

And then call it:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeWrapper<SomeValue>> ptr = getTypeReference()
```

Comment: I understood that ParameterizedTypeReference is an abstract class, but why do we no need to implement the abstract methods of this abstract class?  Cos my understanding is that new ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeWrapper<SomeValue>>() {} is actually instantiating an anynomous class that extends ParameterizedTypeReference, but yet, how come no need to implement abstract methods of this ParameterizedTypeReference class ?

Comment: sorry, i think i know the reason why. Cos ParameterizedTypeReference is an abstract class without abstract methods